# Jquery removeclass with buttons

Tags: jquery, html

How can I target a subset of all buttons with a specific class? What i'm trying to accomplish is, that only one button with P or S can be selected at a time. If a user clicks on a specific "P" button it removes the highlight class from every other "P" button, same with "S".

http://jsbin.com/adopuz/1/edit

```
$(':button').on('click', function() {

      var typeid = $(this).attr('value');
      $(this).addClass('highlight');

      if(typeid == 'P') {
        $('.primary').val(0);

        $(':button').removeClass('highlight');

        var opts = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(0).val(1);


      }

      if(typeid == 'S') {

      $('.static').val(0);
      var optp = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(1).val(1);

      }

    });
```

### HTML

```
  <div id= "US">
    This is the US
  <div id="Monday">

<input name='' value='1' class="primary" type=''>
<input name='' value='0' class="static" type=''>


<input type='button' value='P' class='P'>
<input type='button' value='S' class='S'>

  </div>

    <div id="Tuesday">

<input name='' value='1' class="primary" type=''>
<input name='' value='0' class="static" type=''>

<input type='button' value='P' class=''>
<input type='button' value='S' class=''>


  </div>

      <div id="Wednesday">

<input name='' value='1' class="primary" type=''>
<input name='' value='0' class="static" type=''>


<input type='button' value='P' class=''>
<input type='button' value='S' class=''>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a little error in your HTML: you've only set the 'P' or 'S' class in the first couple of buttons. The next ones have '' as class. You must set the class for the following code to work.

Fixed that, you should first unset all the 'highlight' classes, and then set the one you're interested in:

http://jsbin.com/adopuz/8/edit

```
$(':button').on('click', function() {

  var typeid = $(this).attr('value');

  if(typeid == 'P') {
    $('.primary').val(0);

    $(':button.P').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');

    var opts = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(0).val(1);
  }

  if(typeid == 'S') {
    $('.static').val(0);

    $(':button.S').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');

    var optp = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(1).val(1);
  }
});
```

Comment: $(this).addClass('highlight'); - Is written twice meanwhile you should write it once after checking of the typeid, unneeded redundancy.

Comment: @MuhammadHani: I know, but that way the example is easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/adopuz/3/edit

You can filter your :button selection with a class selector, such as `:button.P`  You can do it in jquery long form, if you prefer it to be more readable, with `$(':button').filter('.P')`

It looks like my changes didn't save.  Not sure what's up with that!  But I added `.P` to your filter in the top block, where you `removeClass` and added the same line to the bottom but for `.S`.  I also added classes `P` and `S` to all your buttons.  And lastly, I moved your `addClass` call to the bottom of the page, so your `removeClass` didn't accidentially remove the newly clicked button!

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you want to be able to highlight only ONE button from those who have the 'P' class. same thing with 'S' class buttons?

To select all buttons with 'P' class as an example, slightly change your code from `$(':button')` to `$(':button.P')` , that means getting all buttons with 'P' classes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WaBQ2/)

```
  if(typeid == 'P') {
    $('.primary').val(0);   
    $(':button.P').removeClass('highlight');  
    var opts = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(0).val(1);

  }

if(typeid == 'S') { 
  $('.static').val(0);      
  $(':button.S').removeClass('highlight');     
  var optp = $(this).parent().find('input').eq(1).val(1);  
  }
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: This is good, but I would like it to remove the highlight class from every "P" or "S" button except the one you currently clicked on.

Comment: @Edward - The last linr added the class again to the clicked one. - $(this).addClass('highlight'); - There is an extension method to remove classes except selected one here - http://thetimbanks.com/2011/10/19/jquery-extension-removeclassexcept-method/